# Withdrawing ETH from contract

Tags: ether

I sent eth to a contract address associated with my wallet by mistake. Is there a way to withdraw the eth?

https://etherscan.io/address/0xd7830d8224B65eaF24dE37748f69820F81368f59

Answer (score 0):

A contract can only return funds if it has such functionality programmed into it prior to deployment. You need to contact the contract owner to be sure.

Comment: The contract was created by my eth address. Im not sure how but it looks like it is associated with my sending NFTS to my ledger https://etherscan.io/address/0xb36d0655799f8bd1adcc46c13d643c5b0ada897a

Comment: I have verified the address in Etherscan so can access the contract